# Вывести товары в наличии на страницу сайта Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Уважаемые коллеги!

Голову сломал, не могу найти решение. Направьте пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать.

Задача: Вывести на лендинг битрикс товары, количество которых не равно нулю. (То есть товары в наличии)
Так же есть отчет "Складские остатки" 1С-битрикс, сихронизируется с Битрикс 24. Как вариант можно вывести его на сайт.

Буду благодарен за любые идеи и предложения!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша задача решается с помощью стандартного GetList:

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 1, ">CATALOG_QUANTITY"=>0, "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
 $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
 print_r($arFields);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Вывел товары в наличии в таком виде https://prnt.sc/1w499lj

Подскажи, пожалуйста, как можно вывести в красивом виде?

Comment: Для читабельности используйте тег pre:

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arFields);
echo '</pre>';

Comment: а как сделать кнопку ?